# OpenIdConnectProtocolException: Message contains error: 'invalid_request', error_description: 'AADB2C90079:

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c

I am using the Azure AD B2C authentication in my ASP .NET Core web app. I also want to get notification after successful authentication of user so that I can add custom roles and for that I am trying to register OnAuthorizationCodeReceived callback. But as soon as I do it I am getting following exception...

OpenIdConnectProtocolException: Message contains error: 'invalid_request', error_description: 'AADB2C90079: Clients must send a client_secret when redeeming a confidential grant.

The original code in the Setup.cs which works is...

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(AzureADB2CDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddAzureADB2C(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options));

        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddRazorPages();
    }
```

But when I add following code in ConfigureServices() function...

```
        services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADB2CDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
        {
            options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
            options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
            {
                OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived,
            };
        });

public async Task OnAuthorizationCodeReceived(AuthorizationCodeReceivedContext context)
{
}
```

It starts generating above mentioned exception when I click on Signin button. Looks like I am able to authenticate and I get OnAuthorizationCodeReceived callback too. But once control returns from OnAuthorizationCodeReceived that exception occurs with following stack...

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.RedeemAuthorizationCodeAsync(OpenIdConnectMessage tokenEndpointRequest)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.HandleRemoteAuthenticateAsync()

Please let me know what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Nan Yu for your reply.

Finally I am able to fix that by using following code

```
services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADB2CDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
    {
        options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
        {
            OnTokenValidated = OnTokenValidated
        };
    });
```

So initializing options.ResponseType is really not necessary and OnTokenValidated worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow since you are setting `code` to `ResponseType` in OIDC config :

```
options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
```

Please check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) , code flow need `client_secret`when requesting ancess token if your app is  web apps or web APIs .

If you want to add custom roles after login , `OnTokenValidated` event offers you the chance to modify the ClaimsIdentity obtained from the incoming token , code below is for your reference :

```
options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
{
    OnTokenValidated = ctx =>
    {
        //query the database to get the role

        // add claims
        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin")
        };
        var appIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims);

        ctx.Principal.AddIdentity(appIdentity);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    },
};
```

But if you want to query the Microsoft Graph , then use `OnAuthorizationCodeReceived` event and use MSAL to get access token for Microsoft Graph .